# Solving css issue

Tags: css

I'm very new to coding and I been following a tutorial to make an online graphic design portfolio but I cant seem to get my css to work. I'm trying to import a font. Would really appreciate some feedback, Thanks!

I've made sure my folders are set up correctly, but nothing seems to be working.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
    family=Nunito:300,400,700');
    
body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  background: #EFF1F7;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

This should be Nunito
```

Comment: remove line break after `?` and before `family`

Answer (score 0):

Your reference url to the font is split over multiple lines making it invalid.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300,400,700');
    
body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  background: #EFF1F7;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

This should be Nunito
```